# jquery selector - selecting all span tags with id not equal to something

Tags: jquery

I want to select all HTML `<span>` elements that don't have an `id` equal to `x` and hide them them.  Is this possible?  I think you have to use the `:not` selector but I can't work it out:

`$('span:not(#x').attr('style', "display: none;");`

Any ideas?  Thank you :).

Comment: Looks like you forgot a ). Does this work? $('span:not(#x)').attr('style', "display: none;");

Comment: As a quick side-note, if you just want to hide the elements, use `$('span:not(#x)').hide()`, as setting the style attribute to `display: none;` will replace all existing inline styling, whereas `hide()` will only add `display: none;` - and to show, just call `.show()` which will remove only the `display: none;` style.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just forgot a ).

I made a fiddle to show you. http://jsfiddle.net/3U8tD/

```
$('span:not(#x)').attr('style', "display: none;");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('span[ID!="x"]').attr('style', "display: none;");
```

sets the style attribute of all spans, wich has **NOT** the id x, to none.

**hope this helps**

Comment: Should be $('span[ID!="x"]').attr('style', "display: none;");

Answer (score 3):

There are at least three ways to do what you need.

```
$('span:not(#x)').attr('style', "display: none;");
$('span[id!="x"]').attr('style', "display: none;");
$('span').filter(':not(#x)').attr('style', "display: none;");
```

The most efficient way is `$('span[id!="x"]').attr('style', "display: none;");`

See http://jsfiddle.net/xpAeK/

Comment: The [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) now say: `The .not() method will end up providing you with more readable selections than pushing complex selectors or variables into a :not() selector filter. In most cases, it is a better choice.`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('span[id!="x"]').attr('style', "display: none;");
```